# Підводити чи підбивати підсумки?

Tags: вживання-слів

Вже довгий час цікавить таке питання: як правильно вживати словосполучення "підводити підсумки" чи "підбивати підсумки"? [В Академічному словнику зазначається](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidsumok), що можливе вживання обох варіантів:

*Підбивати (підбити, підводити, підвести, робити, зробити і т. ін.) підсумок (підсумки) — робити висновок із чого-небудь, узагальнювати щось.*

Не впевнена, але вважаю, що краще вживати "підбивати підсумки".

Comment: подивіться, будь ласка, як я відредаґував питання. виглядає краще? якщо так, то, будьте ласкаві, наступного разу робіть свої пости більш читабельними.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На [Офіційному сайті Української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/slovnik_sinonimiv/p/pidsumovuvati/38-1-0-11611), щодо якого вже один із дописувачів
Ukrainian Language beta наголошував, що (сайт) є не офіційним, вказано таку інформацію:

> ПІДСУМОВУВАТИ
>
> Синоніми до слова ПІДСУМОВУВАТИ: підбивати балянс , підводити підсумки; П. узагальнювати, робити висновки . ПІДСУМОК, МАТ. сума; (діяльности) наслідок, результат, ур. АПОТЕОЗА.

На сайті [Мова- ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/antusurzhuk/pidbuvatu-pidsumku) доволі цікавий приклад подають:

> Підводять очі олівцем, а підсумки підбивають.

Таку ж інформацію подає й Волощак М. ([Неправильно-правильно](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=25&t=5680)) та Рогоза Б. ([Уроки державної мови](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/98.htm))

У [Словнику української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidbyvaty), якщо ввести слово "підбивати" знайшла такі варіанти:

> Підбивати (підбити) риску (рисочку), підбивати (підбити) під свою руку,  клинці підбивати,  підбивати (підбити) ноги,  підбивати (підбити) на гріх.

Як бачимо, варіанту "підбивати підсумки" нема. Проте якщо ввести "підсумок" - вискакує Ваша інформація:

> Підбивати (підбити, підводити, підвести, робити, зробити і т. ін.) підсумок (підсумки).

На сайті [Оnlinecorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8/) вказано, що варіант ***"підводити підсумки"*** використовувати *не рекомендовано* (!), бо вважається, що це скалькована конструкція, Тож варто її краще замінити на стилістично правильний варіант: **підбивати підсумки, підсумовувати**. Такого ж висновку дотримуюсь і я.

Answer (score 3):

Якщо подивится на ГРАК-10, то в текстках частіше вживається "підбити підсумки"

CQL для пошуку:

- `[lemma="підвести"][][lemma="підсумок"]` — [60 результатів](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%5Blemma=%22%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%22%5D%5B%5D%5Blemma=%22%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%22%5D);
- `[lemma="підбити"][][lemma="підсумок"]` — [217 результатів](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%5Blemma=%22%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%22%5D%5B%5D%5Blemma=%22%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%22%5D).